# Maple Riemann Zeta Function does not output 0

Tags: riemann-zeta, maple, zeta-functions

I tried using the Zeta function in Maple, though instead of using Zeta directly I used Sum:

```
sum(1/i^s,i=1)
```

The problem here though, is that if:

```
s := 0.5 + 3i

then
sum(1/i^s, i=1) = 1.011077905
```

This does not output 0, which is what it is supposed to be, proven by Riemann, so it eventually means that I have done something wrong. I would be grateful for some help,

Thanks.

Comment: $\zeta(0.5+3i)$ isn't equal to zero. The "first" non-trivial zero is at about $0.5+14.1i$.

Comment: (1) The first nontrivial zero of $\zeta (s)$ occurs at $s = \frac{1}{2} + 14.13472514... i$. (2) The series $\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{1}{n^s}$ converges if and only if $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$. Zeta function for $\operatorname{Re} s < 1$ is not the sum you are trying to evaluate...

Comment: What makes you say it's supposed to output $0$?

Comment: That's just what I thought it would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that there is a confusion between $i$ (the index) and $i$ (the imaginary number) ! $$\zeta (s)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^s}$$ and $$\zeta \left(\frac{1}{2}+3 i\right)\approx 0.532737 -0.0788965 i$$ What it seems it that you computed $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {n^{\frac{1}{2}+3 n}}\approx 1.0110779057055353498$$

Comment: You are right, the thing is, if I use "n" in maple instead of i, it gives me an error:
Error, (in sum) summation variable previously assigned, second argument evaluates to 3 = 1 .. infinity

Comment: Ah, also in Maple the imaginary unit is I (not i).